# Why is this SocketException not caught by a generic catch routine?

Tags: c#, try-catch, socketexception

Our company provides a network component (DLL) for a GUI application.

It uses a Timer that checks for disconnections. If it wants to reconnect, it calls:

```
internal void timClock_TimerCallback(object state)
{
  lock (someLock)
  {
    // ...
    try
    {
         DoConnect();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log e.Message omitted
        // Raise event with e as parameter
        ErrorEvent(this, new ErrorEventArgs(e));
        DoDisconnect();
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

So the problem is, inside of the DoConnect() routine a SocketException is thrown (and not caught). I would assume, that the catch (Exception e) should catch ALL exceptions but somehow the SocketException was not caught and shows up to the GUI application.

```
protected void DoConnect()
{
    //
    client = new TcpClient();
    client.NoDelay = true;
    // In the following call the SocketException is thrown
    client.Connect(endPoint.Address.ToString(), endPoint.Port);
    // ... (login stuff)
}
```

The doc confirmed that SocketException extends Exception.
The stacktrace that showed up is:

```
TcpClient.Connect() -> DoConnect() -> timClock_TimerCallback
```

So the exception is not thrown outside the try/catch block.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: Does this problem occur only when a debugger is attached or always when the code is running?  Also catch is guaranteed to catch all exceptions in the try block - but if your DoConnect performs a fire and forget that sources the exception, DoConnect will return and processing will continue causing the exception to be unhandled by your intended handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little program and was unable to reproduce, a SocketException was caught inside a TimerCallback just fine.

So I suggest you re-think your analysis, the problem may not be what you think it is. A few suggestions:

- run it outside the Timer. T|hat takes the threading out of the loop.
- run it in the debugger. Where does the exception really occur?
- step through the exception handling. Is ErrorEvent doing what it should?

Comment: Thank you, I asked the question because I also had no explanation why this happened and was hoping for new inspiration. I don't think it's reproducable (as your program showed) but it obviously happened, so I had to investigate..

Comment: The behaviour is still not reproducable, so I added debug code and will wait if it occurs again. Accepting your answer because it is most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

If `ErrorEvent` really raises another exception (per the comment), then `DoDisconnect()` is never executed.

Otherwise, the exception you see might be coming form `DoDisconnect()`

Comment: see the added stacktrace why this can't be the solution

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the DoConnect() code?

Also things to try:
Can you catch it in the DoConnect()? 
Try catching the specific exception instead of just the generic.
How does it react if you use debug mode?

Comment: Reading the replies you left to others, leave your code as is but add a SECOND catch block to catch either a SocketExeption or a Win32Exception.

Comment: added the DoConnect() method as requested. Do you also have an explanation for your idea as SocketException extends Win32Exception extends ExternalException extends Exception ?

Comment: There are two reasons, .NET 1.1 win32exception wasn't derived from Exception.  Otherwise, your exception isn't caught likely because it is thrown on a different thread started inside DoConnect.

Comment: so you say TcpClient.Connect() surrounded with a generic try/catch will not always catch all exceptions the call may produce?

Answer (score 0):

Your `timClock_TimerCallback` isn't called in the same thread as the catch-statement wants to catch an exception. You should catch the exception inside `timClock_TimerCallback` and then call a method which invokes itself and then rethrow the exception in the right thread.

Not sure this will work, but you could give it a try.

Comment: That sounds interesting.. but the TcpClient.Connect() is called from the TimerCallback thread where also the catch resides, which other thread could be involved?

Comment: Oops, I thougt the timClock_TimerCallback was somehow called in DoConnect, but thats obviously wrong. I'm afraid my answer won't help you.